# Is it possible to submit a part of a form by ajax and another part of the form 'normally'?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

HTML example:

```
<form action='Somepage.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type="file" name "myFile" />
   <input type="text" name="myText" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This form is submitted by ajax today and I discovered the file upload isn't working at all in IE8 so I want to upload the file part "normally" and the text part by ajax.

Is this possible? In which case, how? And I don't want to use hidden iframe/flash solutions. I'm using jQuery and PHP backend.

Comment: No. Once you submit it normally, the ajax does not make any sense - it's response is never displayed, and even its request might be canceled.

Comment: @Bergi but can't I first submit the text inputs by ajax and on the complete: callback do a normal submit of the form for the files?

Comment: Isn't the point of AJAX to submit without reloading the page? When you do the normal submit of the form, that will reload the page.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes but as I wrote in my post: AJAX upload of files doesn't work in IE8.

Comment: @Weblurk: You can, but what use would it have? Is there a dedicated validation on the text inputs or something that would lead to not submitting the files?

Comment: Our question isn't why you want to use normal subnmission for the file, it's why do you need to use AJAX for the text inputs if you're going to submit the form normally afterward? Just submit the entire form normally in one step, forget about AJAX on IE if file upload doesn't work.

Comment: @Barmar: You're right. I was just trying to save some time handling the text fields since in the live example there are like 15 of them, mixed between textareas and regular text, which need separate character count validation etc. I guess submitting the entire form normally is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the fields that you want to submit via AJAX outside the form. The Javascript that constructs the AJAX call can gets its data from anywhere.

Or you could have the AJAX callback function mark all the text inputs as `disabled`, and then submit the form normally. Disabled inputs are not included in normal form submission.